# playing with awk command trying to remove first line in input

Tags: command-line, awk

below is my input file, results keep returning "Breed has Votes votes"

```
    Breed, Votes
    Black Lab, 30
    Chihuahua, 2
    Pug, 1
    Corgi, 45
    Shar Pei, 21
    Shih Tzu, 5
    Maltese, 7

#!/bin/sh/awk
##comment The below awk script runs on the file dog_breed.txt, FS refers to field separator which is a comma in this case. We initialize our max variable to 0 and max_breed to the first breed, then iterate over the rows to find the max voted breed.
    
    BEGIN{
            FS=", "
            max=0;
            max_breed=$1
    }
    {
            if(max<($2)){
                    max=$2;
                    max_breed=$1;
            }
    }
    END{
            print max_breed " has " max " votes"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the first record (line) by adding a *rule* to the block:

```
NR > 1 {
        if(max<($2)){
                max=$2;
                max_breed=$1;
        }
}
```

However it's worth trying to understand why you get the result that you do when you *don't* exclude the first line - that's because:

- when `NR==1`, the value of `max` is `0` (numeric - assigned in the `BEGIN` block) but the value of `$2` is `Votes` (which is a string). So the expression `max<($2)` converts `max` to a string and performs a lexicographical comparison. If `0` is less than `V` in your locale, then the result is TRUE, and `max` is assigned the *string value* `Votes`
- for subsequent lines, `$2` is numeric, but `max` is now a string so `$2` gets converted to a string and again the comparison is lexicographical. Assuming `V` has a greater lexicographical weight than any of the digits `0` thru `9`, `V` always wins.

As an aside, your shebang looks invalid - it likely should be

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
```

or

```
#!/bin/awk -f
```

depending on your Ubuntu version. Also, assignments like `max_breed=$1` aren't really meaningful in a `BEGIN` block, since it is executed *before* any records have been processed.